Google Analytics integration with laravel 10
I am trying to connect laravel with google analytics. I am using package for that. I unable all the settings from google and added credentials file in my project.
but it is giving me this error

There was no property ID specified. You must provide a valid property ID to execute queries on Google Analytics.

Even though I added property_id in my analytics.php
Here is my Analytics.php file
<?php

return [

/*
 * The property id of which you want to display data.
 */
'property_id' => env('property_id'),

/*
 * Path to the client secret json file. Take a look at the README of this package
 * to learn how to get this file. You can also pass the credentials as an array
 * instead of a file path.
 */
'service_account_credentials_json' => base_path('google/hakidd.json'),

/*
 * The amount of minutes the Google API responses will be cached.
 * If you set this to zero, the responses won't be cached at all.
 */
'cache_lifetime_in_minutes' => 60 * 24,

/*
 * Here you may configure the "store" that the underlying Google_Client will
 * use to store it's data.  You may also add extra parameters that will
 * be passed on setCacheConfig (see docs for google-api-php-client).
 *
 * Optional parameters: "lifetime", "prefix"
 */
'cache' => [
    'store' => 'file',
],
];

Further more I tried this tutorial approach but still same error.
I am getting data in google analytics dashboard but I want to show it on my website.
Do I need to add something in my .env file as well?
or should I change property_id with view_id?

"Do I need to add something in my .env file as well?" - most probably, as you read the propertyId from there through env('property_id'). Also, is this a problem with Laravel itself or with any JS code which you haven't shared?
